# Auth::check() and before('auth') = always sql request for every page?

Tags: sql, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

Am I messing with something or does Laravel conduct sql request to grab data from user table even if all i do on specific page is Auth::check() or have before('auth') filter in router? It can not "get" that user is logged in just from session data (login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc = user_id etc) without

```
select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1
```

? 
There is some security or other risen to not deal just with session data in case of simple checking of user status (i would prefer to make 1 request per session (not per page) to mysql for user data (or else) and than store it in session, and session set to store in memcached or redis and i am wondering can i get that "out of the box"\without serious changes in Authentication system of framework)?

Comment: Can you simply ask the question by rephrasing it, I'm confused and didn't get what you are trying to do ?

Comment: is there a way to do Auth::check() without sending sql request? is there a way to use before('auth') filter without sending sql request?

Comment: You can store the user data in a session.  But then you have to worry about updating the cache anytime the user's data changes.  Honestly though, a single db query per user - even for many, many users - is trivial for even a modest server.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it's instance in the container when you check it for the first time

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    App::singleton('myApp', function(){
        $app = new stdClass();
        if(Auth::check()) {
            $app->user = Auth::User();
            $app->isLogedin = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            $app->user = false;
            $app->isLogedin = false;
        }
        return $app;
    });

    $myApp = App::make('myApp');
    View::share('myApp', $myApp);
});
```

Now in every view, you can check like this

```
@if($myApp->isLogedin)
    Hello {{ $myApp->user->user->user_name }}!
@endif
```

In any controller, you can use it like

```
$myApp = App::make(myApp); // Get it from the container
// do whatever you want to do
```

So, you can check logged in or not and also can use `Auth::user()` object using `$myApp->user`.

Comment: but it use Auth::check() and check() sending 1 sql request every time script requested or i wrong? I digg a little bit and found Auth::guest() - can it do job of Auth::check() or i missing some problem cases? + is there similar "not guest" filter to replace before('auth') without harm?

Comment: Yes, only once it's making the `sql` query and for the rest of your check you don't have to make queries.

Comment: but after you do check() - you don't have to make anoter sql request even without your solution :) it stile 1 select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1 - my question is about how to do that request only one time per entire user session not 1 time per every user request to app\site

Comment: Then you have to put it in the session using `Session::put('key', 'value');` and everytime you can use `if (Session::has('key'))`.